# How should I progressively add results to a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to initialise a matrix in MATLAB and add things to it with a loop. I am unsure of how big it should be to start off with, but I want to be able to add as many sub-matrices to it as is required.

Comment: Yes, the `[]` defines and empty matrix, and `{}` and empty cell.

Answer (score 6):

You can define it empty:

```
matrix = [];
```

and then append rows, columns, or submatrices:

```
matrix = [matrix; newSubMatrix];
matrix = [matrix, newSubMatrix];
```

However, enlarging the matrix this way causes Matlab to reallocate memory. If this happens at each loop iteration your code will be slow.

A better approach is to initialize to an approximate size:

```
matrix = zeros(M,N);
```

and then fill elements in:

```
matrix(m,n) = exampleEntry;
matrix(m,:) = exampleRow;
matrix(:,n) = exampleCol;
```

This way, only if `m` or `n` get larger than `M` and `N` does Matlab need to enlarge the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to initialise a larger matrix:

```
x=nan(n,m)
```

After adding your data, cut it:

```
[a,b]=ind2sub(size(x),find(~isnan(x),1,'last'))
x=x(1:a,1:b)
```

This assumes you do not use nan in your data.